# Cannot inject javax.mail.Session, jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jboss7.x

Jboss can't inject smtp server configuration into Session field.

I've edited standalone.xml file:

```
<mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/MyMail">
        <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp-my-mail">
               <login name="login" password="passwd"/>
        </smtp-server>
</mail-session>
...
<socket-binding-group ...>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp-my-mail">
        <remote-destination host="my-stmp-server" port="2587"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
```

My class which has Session field:

```
@Stateless
public class MailHelper {

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/mail/MyMail")
    private Session mailSession;

    public String send() {
        MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        try {
            m.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "g@gmail.com");
            Transport.send(m);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "...";
    }
}
```

Mail helper is used in jsp page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <jsp:useBean id="mailHelper" class="com.MailHelper" scope="session"/>
    <%= mailHelper.send()%>
</body>
```

Every time I have null in mailSession field. What is wrong?

Comment: How is MailHelper instantiated and used?

Comment: I've edited first post.

Comment: Just one question. Are you sure, this should work this way? With jsp:useBean you instatiate an instance of MailHelper but it's a pure JavaBean then, not a Stateless Session Bean of the JBoss JEE Container. That's the way I understand the jsp:useBean.

Answer (score 1):

The MailSession and the outbound-socket are configured correctly. In the SLSB MailHandler, availabe under java:global/YourProj/MailHelper!youpackage.MailHelper and so on, there must be an injected session. There should be something like that in the server.log:

```
java:global/TestJSP/MailHelper!example.MailHelper
java:app/TestJSP/MailHelper!example.MailHelper
java:module/MailHelper!example.MailHelper
java:global/TestJSP/MailHelper
java:app/TestJSP/MailHelper
java:module/MailHelper
```

Otherwise your project would not be deployed.
But the mailHelper is in the Context of the org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet a JavaBean not a SLSB. You have no DI there. But you can lookup the javax.mail.Session manually in this way

```
 public String send(){
    try {
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        session = (Session)c.lookup("java:jboss/mail/MyMail");
        System.out.println();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Or instantiate it in the standard constructor:

```
  public MailHelper() {
   ini();
}

void ini(){
    try {
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        session = (Session)c.lookup("java:jboss/mail/MyMail");          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```